# Xcode with phonegap provide build error

Tags: ios4, cordova

I have installed phonegap on MAC and installed Xcode 3.1. then open codex and create new project and built and ruis target might include its own product. build failed. give me a solution to this

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a provisioning profile installed on the iPhone you are trying to run it on? For me it sounds you don't have the signing correctly.